# Haskell pattern binding destructively modifies variable?

Tags: haskell

I'm a little new to Haskell, but this behavior is bizarre to me. If I have a simple function defined as follows:

```
foobar :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Integer
foobar x y = case y of
  (a:x:b) -> x
  _ -> -1
```

I'm basically expecting that the function should evaluate to the first argument of foobar if y contains at least two elements and the second element of y is just the first argument of foobar. Otherwise get a -1. But in ghci:

```
foobar 5 [6,7]
```

gives me 7, not -1.

How do I make sense of this behavior?

Comment: try `:set -Wall` in your GHCi sessions to get warnings for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you are doing here is not "updating" the `x` variable but shadowing it.
You are creating a new variable called `x` in the scope of the first branch of
your case statement.

You cannot use a case statement to compare equality as I believe you are
trying to do. If that is your goal, you will need to do something like

```
foobar :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Integer
foobar x y = case y of
    (a:x':b) | x == x' -> x
    _                  -> -1
```

Comment: To add: you can't write this function as `foobar x (_:x:_) = x; foobar _ _ = -1` for similar reasons. There is a good reason for not putting equality tests in pattern matching (except for n-patterns, unfortunately): not every type is in `Eq`, so `==` and `/=` are not defined for every type.

Comment: I don't think that's a good reason.  If a pattern needs `==`, then have that pattern generate the appropriate `Eq` constraint.   I think there are other decent reasons for Haskell's choice though; e.g. you can see whether something is a binder or an equality without considering the lexical context (because it's always a binder), which means that importing names can't change the semantics of working code, only make it ambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

You can tell that `x` is *not destructively updated* by adjusting your code like so:

```
foobar :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Integer
foobar x y = (case y of
    (a:x:b)  -> x
    _        -> -1
    ) + x
```

The `x` at the end will use the original `x` value; it is not destroyed, rather, the `x` binding inside the `case` expression is shadowed. Calling `foobar 5 [6,7]` will produce 12, not 14.